# Form sending OneToMany to Database fails (Symfony2 / Doctrine)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a form that uploads a file and I am trying to "attach" the correct job id/entity to it, but it seems I don't fully understand the concept of table relations:

My File class

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Job", inversedBy="file")
 */
protected $job;
```

My Job class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="job")
 */
protected $file;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->file = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

I am submitting the form and entering everything into a database:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $file = new File();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
        ->add('file')
        ->add('job','text')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {


        $job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->find($form->getData()->getJob());

        $file->setFile($form->getData()->getFile());
        $file->setPath($form->getData()->getPath());
        $file->setJob($job);

        $em->persist($file);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute("pendingJobs");
    }
```

Submitting the form ends in a fatal error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\File::setJob() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Job, string given, called in /var/www/html/web2gdv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 410 and defined

I tried debugging what was send with

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

        dump($form->getData());
        die();
}
```

but it does even get to the point?!

What am I doing wrong?

Any hint appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @julien-bourdic I updated my form like this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/job/pending", name="pendingJobs")
 */
public function jobAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $file = new File();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
        ->add('file')
        ->add('job','entity',array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Job',
            'choice_label' => 'id',
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->find($form->getData()->getJob());

        $file->setFile($form->getData()->getFile());
        $file->setPath($form->getData()->getPath());
        $file->setJob($job);

        $em->persist($file);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute("pendingJobs");
    }



    $jobs = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->findBy(array(
        'receipt' => true,
        'receiptStatus' => true,
    ));

    return $this->render(
        'default/pending.html.twig',
        array(
            'jobs' => $jobs,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        )
    );


}
```

The whole purpose of this class is to have a table where the last button each row is an upload form. How can I populate multiple forms from one class, is that even possible? What yould I have to send to the `render`function?

Comment: Can we see your full job entity please ?

Comment: There you go, it's quite big: http://pastebin.com/hEFykA41

Comment: For your update : Like a table of job with an upload file button on each line ?

Comment: Exactly... Easier to handle it in a separate controller?

Comment: It is an another question ^^ But to answer, yes it's definitely easier to handle a create and update form if you do it with a single entity in another controller.

Comment: Feel free to answer:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752126/populate-multiple-forms-symfony2

Comment: Nice, I'll see it for you when I got a little bit of free time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitely define your field `job` in your form :

```
->add('job','entity',array(
        'class'=>'AppBundle:Job',
        'property'=>'id',
)
```

Comment: PERFECT! changed `property` to `choice_label` as it is deprecated, but it works. Additional question: How do I populate multiple forms? I will update my question!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `find()` returns array, not a `Job`. Use `findOne()`.

```
$job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->find($form->getData()->getJob());
// $job is and Array
```

do instead

```
$job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->findOne($form->getData()->getJob());
// $job is Job
```

Comment: While that may be correct (rather findOneBy I think), this is not what's causing the fatal, as it does not get past `$form->handleRequest($request);`

Answer (score 0):

You have **add('job', 'text')** and must have a [entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) type, not text

First you need have a 'jobs' in the DB. Then you can change to

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
    ->add('file')
    ->add('job','entity', array('class' => 'YourBundle:Job'))
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task'))
    ->getForm();
```

or short

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
    ->add('file')
    ->add('job')
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task'))
     ->getForm();
```

you will receive select box on the job-field