# Populate Multiple Forms Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I have a Controller where I'm creating a list of open Jobs and populate them in a table via Twig.
What I want now is that the last field of each line is an upload form, so that you can add files to one specific job. Unfortunately I have no idea how to handle form requests for multiple forms in one Controller.

Here is the Controller I have now:

```
/**
 * @Route("/job/pending", name="pendingJobs")
 */
public function jobAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $file = new File();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
        ->add('file')
        ->add('job','entity',array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Job',
            'choice_label' => 'insuranceDamageNo',
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->find($form->getData()->getJob());

        $file->setFile($form->getData()->getFile());
        $file->setPath($form->getData()->getPath());
        $file->setJob($job);

        $em->persist($file);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute("pendingJobs");
    }



    $jobs = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->findBy(array(
        'receipt' => true,
        'receiptStatus' => true,
    ));

    return $this->render(
        'default/pending.html.twig',
        array(
            'jobs' => $jobs,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        )
    );


}
```

The form works perfectly except for the fact it is only one form AND the "Job" entity is a dropdown list. I would like to have it "pre-selected" for each job to have the right id if possible.

I found something about "createNamedBuilder" [HERE](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/multi-formulaire-controller-symfony-2) (last post) but it is in french and neither do I understand french, nor does the [API](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html) help at all.

I thought about a foreach for the `$jobs`, but how do I separate the form handles?

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: please show your File entity

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yNVxpwjL there you go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create three actions in your controller. One for the mainpage, one for each upload form and one to handle the form:

```
/**
 * @Route("/job", name="pendingJobs")
 */
public function jobAction(Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $jobs = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->findAll();

    return $this->render(
                'default/pending.html.twig', array(
                'jobs' => $jobs,
            )
    );
}

/*
 * renders an uploadform as a partial from jobAction
 */
public function jobrowAction(Request $request, Job $job) {
    //$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $file = new File();
    $file->setJob($job); // so that we know to what job this upload belongs!

    $form = $this->createUploadForm($file, $job->getId());

    return $this->render(
                'default/pending_job_row.html.twig', array(
                'job' => $job,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            )
    );
}

/*
 * renders and processes an uploadform
 * 
 * @Route("/job/{id}/update", name="job_upload")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function uploadAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $file = new File();

    // this time we set the job property again cause we only receiced the jobId from the route
    $job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
    if (!$job) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Job entity.');
    }
    $file->setJob($job);

    $form = $this->createUploadForm($file, $id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->find($form->getData()->getJob());

        $file->setFile($form->getData()->getFile());
        $file->setPath($form->getData()->getPath());
        $file->setJob($job);

        $em->persist($file);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute("pendingJobs");
    }

    // if the form is not valid show the form again with errors
    return $this->render(
                'default/error.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            )
    );
}

private function createUploadForm(File $file, $jobId)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($file, array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('job_upload', array('id' => $jobId)),
                'method' => 'POST',
            ))
            ->add('file')
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task'))
            ->getForm();

    return $form;
}
```

Then make two Twig files:

```
{# default/pending.html.twig #}

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <table>
        {% for job in jobs %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ job.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:jobrow', { 'job': job })) }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

and:

```
{# default/pending_job_row.html.twig #}

{{ form(form) }}
```

In your File entity are two methods missing:

```
/**
 * Set job
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Job $job
 *
 * @return File
 */
public function setJob(\AppBundle\Entity\Job $job = null)
{
    $this->job = $job;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get job
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Job
 */
public function getJob()
{
    return $this->job;
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising and logical. I know have a form in each row! However, nothing happens if I submit one form, except for a page reload. No files uploaded, no DB entries. PS: I have the getter/setter, just took the wrong file to pastebin!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer with the french post logic and yours :

```
/**
 * @Route("/job/pending", name="pendingJobs")
 */
public function jobAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $jobs = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->findBy(array(
        'receipt' => true,
        'receiptStatus' => true,
    ));

    foreach($jobs as $job) {


        $file = new File();
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')
                     ->createNameBuilder($job->getId(), new FileType(), $job)
                     ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $forms[] = $form->createView();

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $job = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Job")->find($form->getName());

            $file->setFile($form->getData()->getFile());
            $file->setPath($form->getData()->getPath());
            $file->setJob($job);

            $em->persist($file);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute("pendingJobs");
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        'default/pending.html.twig',
        array(
            'jobs' => $jobs,
            'forms' => $forms,
        )
    );


}
```

And to be cleaner, create a separate formType :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_file_type';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
     $builder
        ->add('file')
        ->add('job','entity',array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Job',
            'choice_label' => 'insuranceDamageNo',
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task'))
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be createNamedBuilder i think? does it set the job property in the File entity?